# Hide bootstrap hamburger icon when no nav-items exists

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm populating nav-tems inside navbar bootstrap component dynamically and there are times when there are no nav-items in which case I want to hide the hamburger icon in device viewports.
I figured `navbar-toggler-icon` is the class responsible for this.
Removing this class when there are no `nav-items` causes a bordered box to appear.

What would be the approach to hide the hamburger element when there are no nav-items?

[**Codeply**](https://codepen.io/SubSul/pen/OKyVzX?editors=1000) of navbar's with nav-items and without nav-items.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Without Nav Items</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav2" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav"></ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 ways to accomplish what you want. 
1. Remove the button altogether.
2. Add 'd-none' to the span class.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Without Nav Items</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav2" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon d-none"></span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess you meant adding `d-none` to the `button` element.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. To the button element inside the span tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one `nav-bar`, you can do something like this to hide if no nav items exist.

```
function isEmpty(el) {
  return !$.trim(el.html())
}

if (isEmpty($('.navbar-nav'))) {
  $('.navbar-toggler').hide();
}
```

Comment: hiding navbar-nav's parent is not causing the humburger to hide

Comment: @SubSul sorry, was hiding the wrong parent. Have edited the code, thanks!

Comment: Hiding .navbar is hiding the entire navbar which is not what I wanted. I just wanted to hide the hamburger. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can do any custom logic inside that, and in your particular case, just do `$('.navbar-toggler').hide();`. I have updated the code.